# Query several hash from redis efficiently

Tags: hash, redis

I want to have some objects data in redis and I want to display all objects in a table.

in SQL I would just get the entire row for all object and display it in a view

in redis, I don't want to query each hash separately, since that will be unbearable slow.

Assuming I know the hash keys and the hash names I want to pull, Is there a way to do this effienctly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you believe querying each hash would be unbearably slow. If you loop through your hash keys and do an HMGET for each with the field names you should be good, provided you pipeline the requests.

Alternatively, you could do this in a Lua script that accepts (some of) the key names as KEYS and the fields as ARGV, returnint the answer in whatever format you need it.

Comment: redis in itself is fast, but the problem is that every request to redis needs to go through ~200ms of RTT, which is causing the result to return slowly. Can I set RedisLabs in europe AWS? that might reduce the network time?

Comment: 200ms is indeed a lengthy rtt. Yes, Redis Cloud is available in AWS eu-west. Is your app running there too?

Comment: yeah, the servers and main db are there. Back when I used redis, I am not sure where the redis was and the server was.. it was a blur

Answer (score 0):

- Store all hash key in a set, let's called it 'hashkeyset'
- Use 'sort' command to retrieve all hash values   sort hashkeyset get *->field0 get *->field1 ... get *->fieldN
- You can find more about 'sort' in this link http://redis.io/commands/sort